# Which GLSL Multi Colour Linear/Radial Gradients Strategy to use?

Tags: opengl-es, glsles

I'm developing using OpenGL ES 2 & GLSL and I'm stuck on how to approach multi coloured / fractioned gradients ( linear and radial ).

I don't know which approach is the best practice:

1. Get a texture of the gradient colours & sample this in the fragment Shader ( essentially working with a regular texture ).
2. Computer generate a texture of the gradient first & sample this in the fragment Shader as above ( no need for PNGs etc of the gradient ) - caching this texture to save regeneration.
3. Use interpolation in the fragment Shader to calculate the fragment value by fragment position - this looks like I'd have to use multiple ifs, a loop, stuff you don't want executed per fragment.
4. Other strategy I haven't conceived of.

I know this question is a bit on the subjective side, but having looked around online for information I've not found anything concrete about how to proceed...

Comment: For anyone reading this in future - I went with option 2 from the above. I generate a texture of the linear / radial gradient in a separate frame buffer, get the texture, which I then cache for better performance. This has enabled me to easily draw gradients, like textures, across any arbitrary 2D shape in the same way as a regular texture, keeping things generic from that point on. Performance, once having made the texture, is the same as drawing any image loaded from disk. As I only generate gradients at infrequent intervals, the performance hit is negligible. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can tell you how to proceed, but you may not like the answer. ;) The main two approaches are sampling a texture, or doing shader calculations. To decide which one is more efficient in your case, you need to implement both, and start benchmarking. There are way too many factor influencing the performance of each to give a generic answer.

One of the major factors is of course how complex your calculations are. But modern GPUs have very high raw performance for pure calculations. Not quite as much for the mobile GPUs you're most likely using since you're asking about ES, but even the latest mobile GPUs have become quite powerful. Branches aren't free, but not necessarily as harmful as you might expect.

On the other hand, texture sampling looks like a single operation in the shader, but based on that alone you should not assume that it's automatically faster than executing a bunch of computations. Texture sampling performance can be limited by many factors, including throughput of the texture sampling hardware units, memory bandwidth, cache hit rates, etc. Particularly if your textures need to be fairly large to give you the necessary precision, memory bandwidth can hurt you, and accessing memory on a mobile device consumes significant power. Also, just the additional memory usage is undesirable since you mostly deal with very constrained amounts of memory.

Of course the performance characteristics can vary greatly between different GPUs. So if you want to make reliable conclusions, you need to benchmark on a variety of devices.

For the approach where you implement the computations in the shader, make sure that it is as optimal as it can be. Avoid branches where reasonably possible, or at least benchmark various options to see how much the branches hurt performance. If there are parts of the computation that are the same for each fragment, pre-compute the values and pass them into the shader. Replace expensive operations by cheaper ones where possible. For example, instead of dividing by a uniform value, pass in the inverse as a uniform, and use a multiplication instead. Use vector operations where possible.

Comment: Most comprehensive answer I've ever had, thank you very much! I will have a go at both & benchmark them as you say, it will be enlightening if nothing else :D